# Ubuntu 23.10 crashes and closes all apps when doing multiple tasks like copy paste multiple windows/desktops

Tags: crash, wayland, 23.10

I have ubuntu 23.10 installed on a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 9 with 32 GB ram. I am connecting to 2 monitors using a dell docking station. There is a lof crashes happening whenever I try to copy text between different windows, lets say from edge browser to slack on another desktop. The crash happens mostly when I am switching between the windows very fast, moving cursor very fast from one screen to another to paste on an app on that screen.

The following logs show syslog contents when that happens.

```
2023-11-17T15:51:27.131545+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[10043]: Window manager warning: Ping serial 1854496 was reused for window W27, previous use was for window W26.
2023-11-17T15:51:27.151823+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[16030]: (EE)
2023-11-17T15:51:27.151977+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[16030]: (EE) Backtrace:
2023-11-17T15:51:27.152048+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[16030]: (EE) 0: /usr/bin/Xwayland (0x55f87307c000+0x1660a2) [0x55f8731e20a2]
2023-11-17T15:51:27.152165+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[16030]: (EE) 1: /usr/bin/Xwayland (0x55f87307c000+0x1661a4) [0x55f8731e21a4]
2023-11-17T15:51:27.152232+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[16030]: (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7efc13000000+0x42910) [0x7efc13042910]
2023-11-17T15:51:27.152294+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[16030]: (EE)
2023-11-17T15:51:27.152348+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[16030]: (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
2023-11-17T15:51:27.152403+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[16030]: (EE)
2023-11-17T15:51:27.152461+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[16030]: Fatal server error:
2023-11-17T15:51:27.152518+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[16030]: (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
2023-11-17T15:51:27.152575+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[16030]: (EE)
2023-11-17T15:51:28.339924+00:00 MYCOMP vmware-player.desktop[16375]: XINFO: IO fatal error.
2023-11-17T15:51:28.340142+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[10043]: Connection to xwayland lost
2023-11-17T15:51:28.340306+00:00 MYCOMP microsoft-edge.desktop[16441]: [16483:16483:1117/155128.339846:ERROR:connection.cc(46)] X connection error received.
2023-11-17T15:51:28.342162+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[10043]: X Wayland crashed; attempting to recover
2023-11-17T15:51:28.344031+00:00 MYCOMP systemd[9705]: Stopped target gnome-session-x11-services-ready.target - GNOME session X11 services.
2023-11-17T15:51:28.344357+00:00 MYCOMP systemd[9705]: Stopping org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service - GNOME XSettings service...
2023-11-17T15:51:28.346396+00:00 MYCOMP systemd[9705]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2023-11-17T15:51:28.349286+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[10043]: Meta.Rectangle is deprecated, use Mtk.Rectangle instead
2023-11-17T15:51:28.350267+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[10043]: Window manager warning: META_CURRENT_TIME used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
2023-11-17T15:51:28.353975+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[10043]: Meta.Rectangle is deprecated, use Mtk.Rectangle instead
2023-11-17T15:51:28.354297+00:00 MYCOMP gnome-shell[10043]: Using public X11 display :0, (using :1 for managed services)
2023-11-17T15:51:28.394467+00:00 MYCOMP systemd[9705]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2023-11-17T15:51:28.394691+00:00 MYCOMP systemd[9705]: Stopped org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service - GNOME XSettings service.
2023-11-17T15:51:28.394852+00:00 MYCOMP systemd[9705]: Stopped target gnome-session-x11-services.target - GNOME session X11 services.
```

Apport error log has the following contents

```
INFO: apport (pid 26983) 2023-11-17 14:10:54,050: called for pid 21276, signal 6, core limit 18446744073709551615, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 26983) 2023-11-17 14:10:54,050: ignoring implausibly big core limit, treating as unlimited
INFO: apport (pid 26983) 2023-11-17 14:10:54,052: executable: /usr/bin/Xwayland (command line "/usr/bin/Xwayland :0 -rootless -noreset -accessx -core -auth /run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.URSSE2 -listenfd 4 -listenfd 5 -displayfd 6 -initfd 7 -byteswappedclients")
ERROR: apport (pid 26983) 2023-11-17 14:10:55,055: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
INFO: apport (pid 26983) 2023-11-17 14:10:55,055: writing core dump to /var/lib/apport/coredump/core._usr_bin_Xwayland.1000.5f508668-a6c5-4640-a1cf-341969a515d8.21276.6779968 (limit: -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same Gnome Shell crash after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10.

Trial and error showed that for me it was VMWare Workstation (Pro) that was causing the crash. If I had even just the background services and kernel modules running, even without a VM/the desktop application running, then I would get the crash after half an hour or so.

I only use VMWare intermittently, so stopping all VMWare services and unloading the kernel modules when not required stops the crash from happening:

```
killall vmware-tray && sudo killall vmnet-bridge && sudo systemctl stop vmware-USBArbitrator.service && sudo systemctl stop vmware.service && sudo modprobe -r vmmon && sudo modprobe -r vmnet
```

You need to do this even after a reboot as the kernel modules will be automatically loaded.

Then to load the kernel modules and start the basic VMWare service, the below works for me allowing a VM to be used again:

```
sudo systemctl start vmware.service && sudo modprobe vmmon && sudo modprobe vmnet
```

I'm unsure if you use VMWare but hope this helps someone else if not.